# What might cause a cookie to not get set in the browser when there is a Set-Cookie header in the response?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, cookies

I'm working on a .net website that uses cookies for forms authentication and I wanted to add another secure cookie to hold access and refresh tokens. The cookie is being added to the `Response.Cookies` and everything seems fine. I used fiddler to inspect the response headers to make sure the `Set-Cookie` header was being set.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Location: /
Set-Cookie: 
    TestTokenCookie=(truncated for brevity); 
    domain=local.foobar.com; 
    expires=Sun, 18-Nov-2018 14:42:56 GMT;
    path=/
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Date: Mon, 20 Aug 2018 13:42:59 GMT
Content-Length: 118
```

The response looks correct but no cookie appears in the browser for it. I'm using Edit This Cookie chrome extension to view what cookies have been set. Here's the code for setting the cookie that I used.

```
public void CreateTokenCookie(TokenCookieData tokenCookieData, HttpContextBase currentContext, bool createPersistentTicket = true)
{
    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
        tokenCookieData.Username,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddDays(90),
        createPersistentTicket,
        tokenCookieData.ToString());

    CreateCookieFromTicket(ticket, TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME, true, currentContext);
}

private void CreateCookieFromTicket(FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket, string cookieName, bool httpOnly, HttpContextBase currentContext)
{
    var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, encryptedTicket)
    {
        HttpOnly = httpOnly,
        Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
        Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
        Expires = ticket.Expiration
    };

    var domain = GetCookieDomain();

    if (domain != null)
    {
        cookie.Domain = domain;
    }

    if (currentContext.Response.Cookies[cookieName] != null)
    {
        currentContext.Response.Cookies.Remove(cookieName);
    }

    currentContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Any ideas why the cookie is not being set in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be your doman "domain=local.test.com;"

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24071239/10241547 for more details

test.com seems to be part of that restricted list

or may be it is the com

```
// com : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.com
com
```

See: https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

Comment: I didn't see test.com in the list, just test.ru also test was just a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue ended up being the length of the value of the cookie. The raw value ended up being about 4105 characters which exceeds the max size of a cookie 4093 bytes.