# Browser ignores cookie if domain is set

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I need to share cookie between two web applications deployed on azure (eg. x1.azurewebsites.net, x2.azurewebsites.net)

I thought that all i need to do is to set a domain:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("TEST", "BLE")
{
Domain = "azurewebsites.net"
});
```

But its not working.

For test purposes I added:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("TEST2", "AQQ"));
```

And this one works ok - but its available only on x1.azurewebsites.net

So the question is whats wrong with the code above?

Is it possible to share cookie like this?

Maybe this is security issue? - i understand that every application hosted on azuerwebsites will have access to information stored in my cookie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my question similar to

[Chrome34 ignores cookies with domain ".cloudapp.net"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024351/chrome34-ignores-cookies-with-domain-cloudapp-net/)

So the cause of my issue is browser checks the publicsuffix.org list for domains and block cookies for security reasons.

For more info please see:
http://publicsuffix.org/

Answer (score 0):

RFC2109 says, that explicit specified domains must start with a dot.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt